# Bootstrap multiple carousel not working on thumbnails click

Tags: html, css

i am using 3 bootstrap modal buttons ,on each button i want to display three different modals,and on each modal i am trying to display three different thumbnail carousels ,but in my code it was working for only the first modal, in first modal thumbnail carousel, on click of each thumbnail the carousel is responding , but in the second and third modal thumbnail carousel ,the thumbnail onclick functionality is not working,can any one solve my problem..please

```css
  .product-slider { padding: 45px; }

.product-slider #carousel { border: 4px solid #1089c0; margin: 0; }

.product-slider #thumbcarousel { margin: 12px 0 0; padding: 0 45px; }

.product-slider #thumbcarousel .item { text-align: center; }

.product-slider #thumbcarousel .item .thumb { border: 4px solid #cecece; width: 20%; margin: 0 2%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer; max-width: 98px; }

.product-slider #thumbcarousel .item .thumb:hover { border-color: #1089c0; }

.product-slider .item img { width: 100%; height: auto; }

.carousel-control { color: #0284b8; text-align: center; text-shadow: none; font-size: 30px; width: 30px; height: 30px; line-height: 20px; top: 23%; }

.carousel-control:hover, .carousel-control:focus, .carousel-control:active { color: #333; }

.carousel-caption, .carousel-control .fa { font: normal normal normal 30px/26px FontAwesome; }
.carousel-control { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); bottom: auto; font-size: 20px; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 30%; width: auto; }

.carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-image: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modal 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Modal 2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Modal 3</button>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>  
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="product-slider">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /carousel-inner --> 
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div>
          <!-- /thumbcarousel --> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="product-slider">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /carousel-inner --> 
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div>
          <!-- /thumbcarousel --> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="product-slider">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
            <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /carousel-inner --> 
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div>
          <!-- /thumbcarousel --> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

ID's have to be **unique**. Give each *carousel* and each *thumbcarousel* an ID of its own and you're good to go. Use classes for styling them.

```css
.product-slider {
  padding: 45px;
}

.product-slider .carousel {
  border: 4px solid #1089c0;
  margin: 0;
}

.product-slider .thumbcarousel {
  margin: 12px 0 0;
  padding: 0 45px;
}

.product-slider .thumbcarousel .item {
  text-align: center;
}

.product-slider .thumbcarousel .item .thumb {
  border: 4px solid #cecece;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 98px;
}

.product-slider .thumbcarousel .item .thumb:hover {
  border-color: #1089c0;
}

.product-slider .item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel-control {
  color: #0284b8;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  top: 23%;
}

.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus,
.carousel-control:active {
  color: #333;
}

.carousel-caption,
.carousel-control .fa {
  font: normal normal normal 30px/26px FontAwesome;
}

.carousel-control {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  bottom: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modal 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Modal 2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Modal 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="product-slider">
          <div id="carousel_1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=1"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=2"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=3"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=4"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=5"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=6"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=7"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=8"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=9"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=10"> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div id="thumbcarousel_1" class="carousel thumbcarousel slide" data-interval="false">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=1"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=2"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=3"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=4"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=5"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=6"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=7"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=8"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=9"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_1" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=10"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /carousel-inner -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel_1" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel_1" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div>
            <!-- /thumbcarousel -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="product-slider">
          <div id="carousel_2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=11"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=12"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=13"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=14"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=15"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=16"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=17"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=18"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=19"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=20"> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div id="thumbcarousel_2" class="carousel thumbcarousel slide" data-interval="false">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=11"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=12"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=13"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=14"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=15"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=16"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=17"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=18"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=19"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_2" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=20"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /carousel-inner -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel_2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel_2" role="button" data-slide="next"><i
                                    class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /thumbcarousel -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="product-slider">
          <div id="carousel_3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=21"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=22"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=23"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=24"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=25"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=26"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=27"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=28"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=29"> </div>
              <div class="item"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/950/500?image=30"> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div id="thumbcarousel_3" class="carousel thumbcarousel slide" data-interval="false">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=21"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=22"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=23"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=24"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=25"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=26"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=27"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=28"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=29"></div>
                  <div data-target="#carousel_3" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/60?image=30"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /carousel-inner -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel_3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel_3" role="button" data-slide="next"><i
                                    class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /thumbcarousel -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the issue of duplicated ids.  All the carousels have id="carousel".  Make it unique like this,

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modal 1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Modal 2</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Modal 3</button>
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>  
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="product-slider">
            <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/sunset.jpg"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /carousel-inner --> 
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div>
              <!-- /thumbcarousel --> 

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="product-slider">
            <div id="carousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/lake.jpg"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /carousel-inner --> 
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div>
              <!-- /thumbcarousel --> 

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="product-slider">
            <div id="carousel3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
                <div class="item"> <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="8" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel3" data-slide-to="9" class="thumb"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-93/data1/images/landscape.jpg"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /carousel-inner --> 
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </div>
              <!-- /thumbcarousel --> 

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```